# How to run example systemml code on e.g. IBM Watson Studio

Tags: systemml

I'm trying to follow the quide

https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-neural-networks-in-parallel-with-keras-and-apache-spark-ea8a3f48cae6#

to try out keras with systemml and spark.

Anyway I could not find the mentioned free spark plan on ibm watson. Can anyone help me to find it or is it just not available anymore?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your IBM Watson Studio (you can have a free account), go to your projects (or create one), in the project go to "Environments" tab and choose one of your existing environments or create a new environment, it allows you to choose the Spark environment described at the URL that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
Acutally that was just the way I was trying out. But I was confused that it says it will consume capasity units per hour and the block said it will be free.

Now I found out, that one has 50 capacities free each month. So I can try the code.